# How to adjust the frequency of YDLiDAR X2

Tags: ros, lidar

I am using YDLiDAR X2 within a ROS environment.
According to the datasheet, the voltage must be varied to adjust the frequency of the LiDAR. However, I apply the same voltage every time, but on some days the LiDAR frequency changes unintentionally. What is the solution for this? The voltage is always 4.8V.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It would be best to directly contact the manufacturer for assistance. https://www.ydlidar.com/contact.html